# Why my array is empty? React reading json api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

This is my json from my Drupal site:

```
[
    {
        title: "I believe every human has a finite number of heartbeats. I don&#039;t intend to waste any of mine.",
        uid: "gestor"
    },
    {
        title: "Man must explore, and this is exploration at its greatest",
        uid: "gestor"
    }
]
```

It has two elements separate by brackets {}
And this is how I am trying to use **Fetch** in my react component.

```
componentWillMount(){
    // Con fetch me conecto al site de Drupal
    fetch('http://rest.dd:8080/all-of-us')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(postPrvSrv => {
      // A cada post lo coloco en un array
      console.log(postPrvSrv.results)
      postPrvSrv.results.forEach(post => {
        let data = {
          title:post.title,
          author:post.uid
        }
        console.log(data);
        // Actualizamos el state para poder renderizar
        this.setState({postPrvSrv:this.state.postPrvSrv.concat([data])})
      })
    })
  }
```

This are my console log results:

`console.log(postPrvSrv.results)` = undefined

`console.log(data);` = Nothing, cuz it broke on line 27.. in the **forEach**

`console.log(this.state.postPrvSrv.length)` = 0. obiusly.

This is the error message:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'forEach' of
>   undefined

And the error from the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of
>   undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're directly returning an array from your Durpal endpoint, then the `postPrvSrv` variable (in your fetch response handler) will be a plain array.

Assuming `postPrvSrv` is an array, then the `.results` field on `postPrvSrv` will be `undefined`.

This is the reason you will be getting the **"Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"** error - you're trying to call `.forEach(..)` on the `.results` field, which is undefined on the `postPrvSrv` array.

To resolve this issue, try adjusting your code as shown in the comments below:

```
fetch('http://rest.dd:8080/all-of-us')
.then(postPrvSrv => {

  console.log(postPrvSrv) // Fix this line to see log of data in console

  postPrvSrv.forEach(post => {  // Fix this line
    let data = {
      title:post.title,
      author:post.uid
    }
    console.log(data);

    this.setState({postPrvSrv:this.state.postPrvSrv.concat([data])})
  })

})
```